# Adding columns to Large Tibbles

Tags: r, dplyr

I am having difficulty adding columns to a large tibble. The code I use works fine for a small mock tibble as shown below. The issue I run into is when I use it on my large tibble with approx. `500 obs. of 100 variables`, it adds the columns but it just tacks them onto the end, rather than placing them where I have specified.

```
>RecordId <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
>Name <- c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e")
>
>theTibble <- tibble(RecordId, Name)
>
>
>theTibble <- add_column(theTibble, a = NA, .before = theTibble$RecordId )
>theTibble <- add_column(theTibble, Month = NA, .before = theTibble$RecordId)
>theTibble <- add_column(theTibble, `Month#` = "23", .before = theTibble$RecordId )
>theTibble$Month <- replace(theTibble$Month, is.na(theTibble$Month), "NOV");
>theTibble
# A tibble: 5 x 5
  `Month#` Month a     RecordId Name 
  <chr>    <chr> <lgl>    <dbl> <chr>
1 23       NOV   NA           1 a    
2 23       NOV   NA           2 b    
3 23       NOV   NA           3 c    
4 23       NOV   NA           4 d    
5 23       NOV   NA           5 e
```

Comment: The placement arguments expect a quoted column name or a column index - you're passing a vector and it seems to be taking the minimum value in the vector as the index.  I'm surprised it doesn't throw an error.  Try `add_column(theTibble, a = NA, .before = "RecordId" )`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to add columns at the start instead of end you can use `cbind`. Also I don't get it why you have `Month` column as `NA` first and then you replace all `NA` values with `'NOV'`, you can assign `'NOV'` directly.

```
result <- cbind(`Month#` = 23, Month = 'NOV', a = NA, theTibble)
result

#  Month# Month  a RecordId Name
#1     23   NOV NA        1    a
#2     23   NOV NA        2    b
#3     23   NOV NA        3    c
#4     23   NOV NA        4    d
#5     23   NOV NA        5    e
```